# How to upload a HTML file in Cypress open the same html(as in browser) in Cypress project and do automation on it

Tags: javascript, file-upload, automation, cypress

I have an HTML file which I want to upload in Cypress project and then run it(as we open in browser any html file)and do automation stuffs on the opened html file.

Answer (score 0):

Just visit using the relative path (from project root)
`cy.visit('./test.html')`
Note that to make this work, you shouldn't add `baseUrl` prop to the 'cypress.json' file

Comment: I am not looking for directly putting a path to visit that html file `cy.visit('./test.html')`  rather I want to upload a html file with automation and then run the html file by `cy.visit('uploaded.html')`

Comment: can you please tell what is the type of your file (local,Buffer,text,etc)